# Logging in Eclipse/Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to log in eclipse in a very simple test app.I have the following:

```
public class Test extends Activity {



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.i("FSDSFS","JJJJJJ");


    }
}
```

I have imported the log via import android.util.Log; and am looking in the LogCat,but I see nothing at all.I clicked on the I with a circle around it in LogCat.

What could I be doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DDMS, click on the Devices button (a tiny mobile phone icon) then select the emulator or device from the list. And here you go. :-)

Comment: Well it shows until the app is fully loaded into the emulator then the log disappears and there is no emulator to choose from.Also getting a ton of errors while the app is booting (alot of errors in LogCat)

Comment: Sometimes emulator get disconnected automatically. I don't know why this happens. I close the disconnected emulator, and when I build my project, eclipse launches a new one. Try this.